# Анимация на кнопке,помощь

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://akar-groupp.com/ Анимация есть на всех кнопках, пульсация постоянная прозрачная. Подскажите как достать себе с этого сайта анимацию данную и подключить?Либо есть готовое решение, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Делать такие вещи с помощью js и svg это зло. 
За исключением, когда эффект должен быть от места клика мышки как в google material. 
Держите тулкит:

```css
body { background: cadetblue }
.btn { margin-bottom: 20px !important; }
.btn {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 72px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 423px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c7a17b;
  border-radius: 36px;
  font-family: Arial;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-outline {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  border: 2px solid #c7a17b;
}

.btn-small {
  line-height: 42px;
  min-height: 42px;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 323px;
  border-radius: 23px;
}

.btn-animate:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 100px;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  animation: btn-animate 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-animate {
    0%  { left: -50%; opacity: .5 }
    25% { left: -25%; top: -200px; width: 600px; height: 600px; opacity: 0 }
    26% { left: auto; top: 100px; opacity: 0 }
    50% { left: auto; right: -50%; top: 100px; width: 300px; height: 300px; opacity: .5 }
    75% { left: auto; right: -25%; top: -200px; width: 600px; height: 600px; opacity: 0 }
    76% { left: auto; right: auto; top: 100px; width: 300px; height: 300px; opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-animate">
  StackOverflow
</div>
<div class="btn btn-outline btn-small btn-animate">
  StackOverflow
</div>
```

Comment: Да, поправлю себя - анимировать абсолютный позишн тоже зло, надо транслэйтом

Comment: Это просто супер)Артем спасибо вам огромное, вы мой спаситель)

Comment: Возможно js и зло для типичных анимаций, но вот эффекта рандомности анимации я в вашем варианте, в отличие от оригинала, не вижу. Поправьте меня, если я не прав. И как зарандомить на css я даже не представляю с ходу) Пойду в гугле почитаю.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, о, а я сразу и не заметил что там рандомно) Всеравно считаю что это не тот случай, когда надо к js прибегать.

Comment: да,отличие есть только в рандоме, но с учетом того, что обычный глаз вряд ли заметить, на чистом css все выглядит намного лучше, чем подключать js)Артему респект)